# WinForms WebBrowser hangs on Flash

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I know this question has been asked and answered many times before, but none of the solutions I've found are working. I have a WinForms app that uses the built-in `WebBrowser` control.

The most common solution I found is to switch the target platform to x86, but that didn't work for me. The `Navigated` event fires, but `DocumentCompleted` is never reached. Any new thoughts about this age-old conundrum?

I'm using C# with .NET 4.5 in Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: Flash is a bag 'o bugs, don't use it.

Comment: @Hans -- Man, I wish that was an option! I'm loading _external_ websites in the browser control, so I have zero control over the situation.

Comment: This is why browsers run web pages in a separate process.  That way it can be killed and keep the browser running.  Always gets a work-out with Flash.  This option is however not available when you embed a browser yourself.  Maybe you shouldn't embed a browser then.  Or make your own process equally easy to kill.